# encode UTF-8 chars no see fine

Tags: php, utf-8

**Hi everybody**

I use dreamweaver for create my websites and always create documents in utf-8 and save in the same codification

And i see this problem today and i don´t understand how it´s possible happend

**For example i have in php file this little code :**

```
<?php
print "sesión";
print "sesión";
?>
```

How you can see , this two words are the same words and has special chars in the "o"

I save this document and when i go to run in the server the first line show perfect but the second no :

```
Sesión
SesiÃ³n
```

**The first line perfect and the second show this Ã³n**

I don´t understand how it´s possible this if all document use utf-8 and in this case the 2 words it´s the same word .....

DOM CODE GENERATE :

```
<div id="forma_col_left">Habilitar Registro de Usuarios</div><div id="forma_col_right">
Si <input name="register[active]" value="si" checked="" type="radio">
No <input name="register[active]" value="no" type="radio">

</div>


<div id="forma_col_left">Avisar Nuevo Registro de Usuarios</div><div id="forma_col_right">
Si <input name="register[advise_new]" value="si" checked="" type="radio">
No <input name="register[advise_new]" value="no" type="radio">

</div>

<div id="forma_col_left">Avisar Verificaciones de Cuenta</div><div id="forma_col_right">
Si <input name="register[advise_new_veritas]" value="si" checked="" type="radio">
No <input name="register[advise_new_veritas]" value="no" type="radio">

</div>


<div id="forma_col_left">Activar Expirar Sesión</div><div id="forma_col_right">
Si <input name="register[session_expire]" value="si" checked="" type="radio">
No <input name="register[session_expire]" value="no" type="radio">

</div>

<div id="forma_col_left">Tiempo para Expirar SesiÃ³n</div><div id="forma_col_right"><input name="register[session_time_expire]" value="1000000000" class="forma_input_text" id="campo_4" type="text"></div>


<div id="forma_col_left">Cerrar Sesión al Cambiar Password</div><div id="forma_col_right">
Si <input name="register[close_session_change_pass]" value="si" checked="" type="radio">
No <input name="register[close_session_change_pass]" value="no" type="radio">

</div>

<div id="forma_col_left">Cerrar Sesión cada 24 Horas</div><div id="forma_col_right">
Si <input name="register[close_session_24]" value="si" checked="" type="radio">
No <input name="register[close_session_24]" value="no" type="radio">
```

Comment: *codification* => *character encoding*

Comment: Are you certain that is all your file contains?

Comment: yes sure , i test and see always this

Comment: For me they are both sesiÃ³n

Comment: I see sesión with different form in the special char in one see ok in other see bad

Comment: I put generate code for see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it's obvious, that in the 2-nd time the letter ó is corrupted, before it is sent to the browser. Please, check php code, generating this letter. Something is wrong with it, not with headers.

Comment: If the user sees it correct and incorrect in the same file with the same bytes (apparently), then it can't be this.

Comment: In the website i have this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> and also i save documents as utf-8 , i don´t understa why happend this

Comment: I couldn't. The two strings are exactly the same when I took a hex dump to examine them. I think the OP has probably made a mistake when describing their problem.

Comment: @user2536883 can you put your whole minimal non-working php file to pastebin. So we could see the same, that you see.

Comment: @user2536883 What browser encoding do you use? What is you change it from western european to utf-8 and vise versa?

Comment: @user2536883 From your code, it's obvious, that in the 2-nd time the letter ó is corrupted, before it is sent to the browser. Please, check php code, generating this letter. Something is wrong with it, not with headers.

Comment: Yes i see the problem , the plugin it´s writte for wordpress and use php utf8_encode and that´s the problem , writte for english but in spanish double encode utf8 in php and in the website meta and this give the error finally :)

Comment: @user2536883 Great :). I updated my answer to the helpful comment, I think it's better.

Comment: @alex Eventually, we found, that it was double encoding in php. It was absolutely non-obvious from the questions.

Comment: Yes sure because i see now in file functions of plugin this issue and finally understand the problem